# How to solve "Unauthenticated" laravel problems

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

When I use my api in auth:sanctum middleware I got an error.

```
 public function listUserMenus(){

        $user = auth()->user();

        if ($user) {
            $menus = $user->menus();
            return response(['menus' => $menus], 200);
        } else {
            return response(['error' => 'error'], 401);
        }
    }
```

and api.php folder:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::get('/user', [\App\Http\Controllers\Api\MenuController::class, 'listUserMenus']);

});
```

And my route list:

```
  GET|HEAD   api/tests ...............................................................................................................................................................  
  GET|HEAD   api/user ............................................................................................................................... Api\MenuController@listUserMenus  
  GET|HEAD   sanctum/csrf-cookie ................................................................................... sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum › CsrfCookieController@show
```

auth()->user() method does not work. I use postman and I send my request include Bearer Token and Header application/json. But message always Unauthenticated. How to solve this problem? I use laravel 10x.

Comment: In which route do you create the token and save it to the database? There are no similar ones in the list.

Comment: Probably the login doesnt work via postman. Maybe try out basic auth?

Comment: This is not all list. Login method saves token info to db. Such as; tokenable_type, token etc. Also, I try basic auth but same result.

Comment: Its `Auth::user()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `sanctum` guard to auth helper:

```
$user = auth('sanctum')->user();
```

Comment: I try it but same result